# How can Prophet Isa return to Earth without violating Prophet Muhammad being the last Prophet?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, prophet-isa

We know that Prophet Muhammad is the last of the Prophets (sometimes referred to as the [Seal of the Prophets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khatam_an-Nabiyyin)):

> Muhammad is not the father of [any] one of your men, but **[he is] the Messenger of Allah and last of the prophets**. And ever is Allah, of all things, Knowing. -- [Qur'an 33:40](https://quran.com/33/40)

We also know that second coming of Prophet Isa will be a sign of the Day of Judgement:

> And indeed, **Jesus will be [a sign for] knowledge of the Hour**, so be not in doubt of it, and follow Me. This is a straight path. -- [Qur'an 43:61](https://quran.com/43/61)

This means Prophet Isa will return to Earth in the future, and in particular, after Prophet Muhammad who is the last of the Prophets.  This is puzzling me.

**Question**: How can Prophet Isa return to Earth without violating Prophet Muhammad being the last Prophet?

Comment: Then angle you're asking the question is insignificant. Isn't it obvious? Prophet Muhammad was the **last to be sent** as the messenger. Having that said Shias believe in [Raj'a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raj%60a) and that Prophet Muhammad would return to this world. So it kind of solves your dilemma

Comment: It's an odd usage of the word "last"; it wouldn't be used like this in other situations: "This is the last piece of cake." "But there's one over there." "That cake was baked first."

Comment: He is the last born. Last one as Nabi. Last religion. Last book. Contrary to the accepted answer I would also argue that he's the last rasool. I mean wasn't Jesus also a Nabi? So the first verse is still nullified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazrat Ayesha (ra) said:

> “Call him the Khatim al-Nabiyyin; but **do not say that there shall not come a Prophet after him.**”
>
> (Al-Suyuti Durr-i-Manthur, Vol. V, p.204)

The same statement of ‘A’isha has been quoted in the Ta’wil al-ahadith of Ibn Qutaiba. In the Durr-i-Manthur a similar statement of Mughira ibn Shu’ba has been quoted through a reference to the Musannaf of Ibn Abi Shaiba:

(It is related) from al-Sha’bi who said that a man sitting near Mughira ibn Shu’ba proclaimed:

> Blessings be upon Muhammad the Last of the Prophets, and there shall not come after him any Prophet! Mughira told him: **When you say Khatim al-Nabiyyin, you need not further say, there shall not come a Prophet after him. For we have been told a hadith (from the Prophet) that ‘Isa is also to be (again) commissioned: and he was sent before him and (will be sent) after him.**
>
> (Durr-i-Manthur, Vol.V, p.264)

Ibn Abi Hatim on the authority of Abu Hurariah that the Prophet once said:

> “I am the first of the Prophets in creation, and the **last of them in being commissioned**."
>
> (Ibn Kathir, Fath al-bayan)

In a long hadith concerning al-Isra’ (Night-Journey of the Prophet), (it is related) on the authority of Abu Hurairah directly from (the Prophet):

> “O Gabriel, who is with you?” He said (to the Angels in reply): “It is Muhammad the Messenger of Allah the Last of the Prophets… (till he said)... Then Allah the Blessed said unto him: I have taken you for my beloved. It is also recorded in the Torah that Muhammad sallallahu alayhi wasallam is the beloved of the Most Beneficent. And We have sent you to all mankind. I have made your Ummah the earliest and the last of all the nations. I have also made your Ummah such as no khutbah (sermon, or address) shall be valid unless people testify that you are My servant and My Messenger. I have made you the first of the Prophets in creation, and the last of them in respect of Commissioned. I also gave you the seven repeated (verses - i.e., the Surat al-Fatiha) and I did not give it to any other Prophet before you: and I have given you the last verses of the Surat al-Baqara from that treasure which is (hidden) under the Throne and which I did not give to any other Prophet. I have also made you a Fatih (an opener) and a Khatim (one who ends a thing).”
>
> (Narrated by al-Bazzar - see Majma’ al-zawa’id, pp.27- 29). This hadith is also narrated in the Khasa’is al-kubra, p.171, on the authority of Ibn Jarir, Ibn Abi Hatim, Ibn Mirdawaihi, Abu Ya’la and al- Baihaqi)

It is clear that the term Khatim al-Nabiyyin and Akhir al- Nabiyyin mean only that the Holy Prophet is the last of the Prophets -peace be upon them - in respect of his **being commissioned (to the people)**. From this point of view, **it is not infeasible or incompatible to any early Prophet to remain (a Prophet) after him or later to be sent to this world.**

And Allah knows best.

---

Source: [muhammadthelastprophet.blogspot](http://muhammadthelastprophet.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/does-khatam-un-nabiyeen-allow-jesus-to.html?m=1)

Comment: As a side-note,  لا نبي بعدي ( there is no prophet after me ) was said by the Prophet ﷺ himself, see [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3455) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2404b), so the quote attributed to Aisha is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Because Jesus (as) will not come in the capacity of a Prophet but as a follower of Muhammad (saws) under his Shari'ah.
See this link: https://youtu.be/AOOqb2wXgPw

Answer (score 1):

Prophet Isa will just come back to help Imam Mehdi. He won't violate Prophet Muhammad being the last messenger because he won't being a new shariah and will follow Islamic teachings. Islam is the last and complete religion sent by Allah and there will be no religion after it so Hazrat Isa won't bring a new shariah. He already taught christianity to his community and has fulfilled his duty he was sent for.

Answer (score 0):

Prophet isa ibn maryam (pbuh) will not descend on earth but as a follower of prophet muhammad (pbuh). so he will no longer be a prophet b'se the prophethood passed on him. He will be a person of truth. real moslem as we are. no message or revelation will be revealed to him from Allah as it is to a prophet."the holy Quran is the last revealed book".
May Allah bless u all.اَلسَلامُ عَلَيْكُم وَرَحْمَةُ اَللهِ وَبَرَكاتُهُ‎